# GML3 features Openlayers not plotting

Tags: openlayers-3

Latest Version of Openlayers 3.

```
var metSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: "metobjectxml/2.xml",
    format: new ol.format.GML3({
        defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
    })
});


var metLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: metSource
});


var mapView = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([-114.3035, 54.5800], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913'),
    zoom: 5,
    projection: 'EPSG:900913'
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [metLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: mapView
});
```

```

Not plotting anything.

XML file: https://bpaste.net/show/56363886838f

Anyone know why?

Comment: @chrki I want to delete that.

Comment: I didn't mean it to be a bad thing, just as a reference for other people when researching this issue. I tried to debug this and couldn't figure it out. Feel free to add "I posted this on the bug tracker <link>" if you want. You might want to post a link on the bug tracker though so the developers will easily find it. Sorry

Comment: @chrki I wanted to delete it because I wasn't sure if It was an issue on my end or there is a problem with openlayers itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by OpenLayers. Only GML simple features profile is supported. What you have seems sensor web related.

Comment: Is there a way to get those coordinates plotted?

Comment: Find a tool that can convert your data to something openlayers can read. Maybe OGR can do it, not sure.